# How to prove that $\mathrm{Iso}\,(\Bbb{Z}_p)\cong \Bbb{Z}_p^{\times}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Denote by $\mathrm{Iso}\,(G)$ the set of all isomorphisms $\psi:G\rightarrow G$. Denote by $\mathrm{Hom}\,(G)$ the set of all homomorphisms $\varphi:G\rightarrow G$. Consider each of these sets with the binary operation given by composition.

Prove that $\mathrm{Iso}\,(\Bbb{Z}_p)\cong \Bbb{Z}_p^{\times}$.

I understand how to solve this for specific cases, but do not know how to prove it generally:

If we are looking at $\Bbb{Z}_3^{\times}$ instead, (we know the order is 2) and we need to find the isomorphisms $\Psi:\Bbb{Z}_3\rightarrow\Bbb{Z}_3$

$\Psi(g)=g$;
$\Psi(0)=0$; 
$\Psi(1)= 2$;
$\Psi(2)= \Psi(1+1)= \Psi(1)+ \Psi(1)= 2+2=1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\Bbb Z_p$ is cyclic. Consider the possible images of a generator under an isomorphism. What are the generators of $\Bbb Z_p$?

*NB*. In case you were: It's not necessary to assume $p$ is prime.